# -bash: memcdump: command not found

Tags: linux, centos

I am try to execute command in centos server for memcached :

```
memcdump --servers localhost
```

but not working.show the error :

> -bash: memcdump: command not found

I can't understand why give it.

Answer (score 3):

Late answer, but I was having the same issue and was looking for a solution. For CentOS you can install the package libmemcached / `sudo yum install libmemcached`.

Now the pitfall: `memcdump` is not available, it is named `memdump` in CentOS. Same for `memccat`, it is `memcat`. It seems this is due in Ubuntu [memdump](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/disco/en/man1/memdump.1.html) being already taken.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the package `libmemcached-tools` (`memcdump` should be a part of this package).

Comment: I have try to install by `yum install libmemcached-tools`
but show the message : ***No package libmemcached-tools available.*

have any option to install `libmemcached-tools`